# How to set any font in reportlab Canvas in python?

Tags: python, reportlab

I'm using reportlab to create pdfs. When I try to set a font using the following method, I get a `KeyError`:

```
pdf = Canvas('test.pdf')
pdf.setFont('Tahoma', 16)
```

But if I use `'Courier'` instead of `'Tahoma'` there isn't a problem. How can I use Tahoma?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Perhabs Tahoma is a TrueType font, and you need to register it first. According to the user guide of ReportLab you need to do this:

```
from reportlab.pdfbase import pdfmetrics
from reportlab.pdfbase.ttfonts import TTFont

pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('Vera', 'Vera.ttf'))
pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('VeraBd', 'VeraBd.ttf'))
pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('VeraIt', 'VeraIt.ttf'))
pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('VeraBI', 'VeraBI.ttf'))

canvas.setFont('Vera', 32)
canvas.drawString(10, 150, "Some text encoded in UTF-8")
canvas.drawString(10, 100, "In the Vera TT Font!")
```

The canvas object has a `getAvailableFonts` method that should return all currently registered (and therefore usable) fonts.

Comment: Thanks you made my day, It worked, is there anyway to use opentype fonts in this way...

Comment: Last time I checked it had no support for opentype. Recently I needed to use a OTF, I could convert it to TTF with fontforge. But as OTF is a newer format, you might loose some features. Fortunately for me it didn't made a difference at that time.

Comment: I wanted to use Consolas font, but it seems opentype, thats why i asked. thanks for the great tip anyway..

Comment: Although I registered one of my downloaded font from the internet.  And it also shows up when calling getAvailableFonts method.  But when I  try to write a copied character using google translate, I find the same rectangle box in the generated pdf. May I know where am I going wrong?

Comment: Great, especially for those who need use iso-8859-2. Ummd, saved lot of my time, thank you.

Answer (score 16):

Start at [Reiner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4900031/8079979).

It is perfect with one caveat.

Reportlab only searches for fonts in **predefined folders**:

```
TTFSearchPath = (
            'c:/winnt/fonts',
            'c:/windows/fonts',
            '/usr/lib/X11/fonts/TrueType/',
            '/usr/share/fonts/truetype',
            '/usr/share/fonts',             #Linux, Fedora
            '/usr/share/fonts/dejavu',      #Linux, Fedora
            '%(REPORTLAB_DIR)s/fonts',      #special
            '%(REPORTLAB_DIR)s/../fonts',   #special
            '%(REPORTLAB_DIR)s/../../fonts',#special
            '%(CWD)s/fonts',                #special
            '~/fonts',
            '~/.fonts',
            '%(XDG_DATA_HOME)s/fonts',
            '~/.local/share/fonts',
            #mac os X - from
            #http://developer.apple.com/technotes/tn/tn2024.html
            '~/Library/Fonts',
            '/Library/Fonts',
            '/Network/Library/Fonts',
            '/System/Library/Fonts',
            )
```

If you're trying to use a ttf font that you've downloaded off of the internet, and would like that font available on all your servers, I would suggest the following:

- Add the font to your project in any directory. e.g.: /project_root/app/lib/reportlabs/fonts/
- Make sure you have something like BASE_DIR/ROOT_DIR in your settings:

  ```
  BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
  ```
- add the following line to a python file that generates pdf:

  ```
  import reportlab
  from django.conf import settings
  reportlab.rl_config.TTFSearchPath.append(str(settings.BASE_DIR) + '/app/lib/reportlabs/fonts')
  pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('Copperplate', 'Copperplate-Gothic-Bold.ttf'))
  ```

Comment: Although I registered one of my downloaded font from the internet.  And it also shows up when calling getAvailableFonts method.  But when I  try to write a copied character using google translate, I find the same rectangle box in the generated pdf. May I know where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

By adding DejaVuSans Font to  application solved my problem.
Here is the snippet of code

```
pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('DejaVuSans','DejaVuSans.ttf'))
```

And use UTF8 for all coding.:)