# How to enable Arabic support in reportlab.pdfgen using drawString()?

Tags: python-3.x, reportlab

I have qr code in `PIL Image` and some Arabic text and trying to put the qr Image on a pdf file. 
I'm using `reportlab.pdfgen`'s `canvas`.

After a lot of searching I found `arabic_reshaper`, someone's project that didn't work, and after reading the source code of `textobject.py` I found that I need to install `pyfribidi`, installed it, and used `drawString(x,y,"مربحا",RTL)` nothing happens.

I'm using `arabic_reshaper` as described in the repository, and the `RTL` from `pyfribidi`

```py
import arabic_reshaper

reshaped = arabic_reshaper.reshape(exam_name)
c.drawString(x - 100, y - 20, reshaped, direction=RTL)
```

The result is always the same, as you can see on the right the English strings appear normally, the Arabic ones appear as black pixels :

[image: a busy cat]

If you have any other recommendations for another library that will be also appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to some developers who noted that the problem is caused by the font I was able to fix it.

First I downloaded an Arabic `TTF` font, and as I'm using `linux` I placed it in `'/usr/share/fonts'` then I did the following:

```
import reportlab
import arabic_reshaper
from bidi.algorithm import get_display
from reportlab.pdfbase import pdfmetrics
from reportlab.pdfbase.ttfonts import TTFont
// BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

reportlab.rl_config.TTFSearchPath.append(str(settings.BASE_DIR))
pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('Arabic', '/usr/share/fonts/tradbdo.TTF'))

ar = arabic_reshaper.reshape(u'العربية')
ar = get_display(ar)
canvas.setFont('Arabic', 32)
canvas.drawString(x - 100, y, ar)
```

and now everything is working just fine.

[Read this answer carefully.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52450839/6916832)