# Python reportlab generate PDF having font issue for word with accents, for example Māngere

Tags: python, pdf, reportlab, non-ascii-characters

How to solve the below font issue?

```
buffer = io.BytesIO()
c = canvas.Canvas(buffer)
c.drawString(100, 100, "Māngere")
c.save()
buffer.seek(0)
return FileResponse(buffer, filename="test.pdf")
```

The code above couldn't display "Māngere" properly on generated PDF, as below:

[image]

Comment: Download `.ttf` file from: https://fonts2u.com/dejavu-sans-condensed  
Place the file in the same folder as the python code, and then follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899885/how-to-set-any-font-in-reportlab-canvas-in-python

Answer (score 1):

As Kacper said above (Im just reposting here to make it more visible), you need to use ttf font.

You can easily register it in this fashion:

```py
from reportlab.pdfbase import pdfmetrics
from reportlab.pdfbase.ttfonts import TTFont

pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('PlexMono', 'IBMPlexMono-Regular.ttf')) #I found this on Google fonts

#...#

canvas.setFont("PlexMono", 20)
```

[Result after writing out to pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGdCV.png)